# How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged without setter?

Tags: c#, listview, inotifypropertychanged

I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged into my class (my goal is, to update a ListView every time an Item from 'JobDataGroup.Items' gets deleted), but in every tutorial, OnPropertyChanged gets called from the setter. Since I have no setter, how do I procede?

My Class:

```
public class JobDataGroup : repVReportsDataCommon, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceJobItem> Items
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<ServiceJobItem>(repVReportsDataSource.GetJobItems().Where(_predicate)); }
    }

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You would fire it as part of the code that deletes the item.

Comment: When one of your items is deleted, you should have the `Items` collection up to date, since you're using an `Observable` collection that listens for changes in the collection (E.g. items deletion or adding).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter from where you call your OnPropertyChanged method, call it when the property needs to be reevaluated.

Since you are recreating your collection every time the getter is accessed, there is no point in using an ObservableCollection. 
You might as well just use a List instead and raise OnPropertyChanged manually:

```
public List<ServiceJobItem> Items { get; private set; }

void UpdateItems() {
    Items = new List<ServiceJobItem>(repVReportsDataSource.GetJobItems().Where(_predicate));
    OnPropertyChanged("Items");
}
```